# ispunct() Function in C++

Tags: c++

```
char punct(char a[], int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (ispunct(a[i]))
            { return i; }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Could anyone tell me why this function is only returning -1 for every string that I hand to it? I'm writing a program to take words from a .txt file and outputting them (with a little bit of alteration) into a different .txt file, and I need to remove punctuation from the strings. However, I cannot seem to detect where the punctuation is using the ispunct() function. I even wrote my own function using all of the cases of punctuation I could imagine and it still only returns -1. Is it a problem with the function here or the strings that I am giving to it? If showing more of my code is necessary, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  This is not directly related to your question, but you probably want to change the return type to `int`. The value `-1` might not be a representable in type `char`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because if `ispunct(a[0])` returns `false`, `return -1` is called.

You should move the default return outside of the loop:

```
char punct(char a[], int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (ispunct(a[i]))
            { return i; }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Note that this function only returns the first punctuation index, not all indexes. I guess you're treating this case outside the function.